# How to get a specific element from the set - PlusCal

Tags: tla+, pluscal

Given the set, for example, {1, 2, 4, 10, 6} how can I get the element 4 to a variable var.
What I want is to get element "4" from the set to a variable var: var = 4
And remove the element 4 from the set: set = {1, 2, 10, 6}

Comment: What's wrong with `var' = 4 /\ set' = set \ {4}`?

Comment: Is 4 a hardcoded value or the result of a check or something?

Comment: values of the set are not hard-coded, what I want is a pluscal code for getting a specific element from the set.

Comment: @option how are you identifying the specific element of the set that you want to get? Are you sure you don't want to use a sequence instead?

Comment: I want to get an element(any element which exists in the set) from the set and assign it to some variable. If I have the set {1, 2, 3} I want to assign one element of this set to a variable

Comment: @option like, "I could assign 1 to the variable _or_ assign 2 _or_ assign 3, pick one?"

Comment: yes, pick one (any of the elements) and assign it to the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you want this:

```
with x \in set do
   var := x;
   set := set \ {x};
end with;
```